# Keep only rows before certain dates, by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have two DataFrames: one has all my `id`, `loan_id` and `date` values for every `loan_id`, and the other has one random `date` value for every `id`:

`df1`:

```
id     date    loan_id
1     201301     100
1     201301     200
1     201302     100
1     201302     200  
1     201303     100
1     201304     100
2     201402     100
2     201403     100
2     201404     100
2     201405     100
```

`df2`:

```
id     date
1     201303  
2     201403
```

What I want to achieve is to create a DataFrame that has all values for an `id` until the date specified in `df2`, like this:

```
id     date    loan_id
1     201301     100
1     201301     200
1     201302     100
1     201302     200  
1     201303     100
2     201402     100
2     201403     100
```

I'm guessing that with a `groupby('id')` and something else I will be able to achieve it, but I'm not finding that "something else". I could do it creating a dummy variable, backfilling by group and dropping the rest, but efficiency is quite important in this problem. Do you know a more efficient way? Thanks.

Edit: Added the fact that the same date can appear twice (or more) for the same `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, set indexes to be the same and use `le`

```
df[df.set_index('id').date.le(df2.set_index('id').date).values]
```

---

```
   id    date
0   1  201301
1   1  201302
2   1  201303
4   2  201402
5   2  201403
```

Comment: The problem was that the `id` weren't sorted. Now it's working as expected! Thank you very much